# How to convert floating-point in for-loop to integer in C, for correct calculation

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to understand C better. In an exercise I had to find out what is wrong about the following code example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int count;
    float sum;
    float i;

    sum = 0, count = 0;
    for (i = 1000; i <= 1000.04; i += .01) {
        sum += i;
        count++;
    }
    printf("Sum: %f, Count: %d\n", sum, count);

    return 0;
}
```

I found out that it's a bad idea to use floating-point in loops because it causes problems bsince it's not accurate. Next step is to rewrite the code, so it does the same thing but without using floating-point in the loop. I'm stuck on this task, I don't know how to replace `i <= 1000.04`. For `i += .01` I guess I could replace it with `i++` and divide it with 100 somewhere else.

Any ideas how to fix it properly?

Comment: *I found out that it's a bad idea to use floating-point in loops* Yes, a very bad idea.

Comment: *I don't know how to replace `i <= 1000.04`* You could do worse than `i <= 100004`.

Comment: *I guess I could replace it with i++ and divide it with 100 somewhere else.*  Right.  Like maybe `sum += i / 100.;`.

Comment: The other thing you should do, besides changing `i` from `float` to `int`, is to change `sum` from `float` to `double`.  Unless you have special requirements and know what you are doing, never use type `float`, always use `double`.  Using type `float` often makes floating-point inaccuracies worse, while type `double` is often good enough.

Comment: Okay thx for your answers! I make sure to always avoid floating-point if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int count;
    float sum;
    int i;

    sum = 0, count = 0;
    for (i = 100000; i <= 100004; i++) {
        sum += i;
        count++;
    }
    printf("Sum: %f, Count: %d\n", sum/100, count);

    return 0;
}
```